# How do I export a Pulumi stack output in Python?

Tags: python, pulumi

I'd like to add an "output property" to my Pulumi program, which is written in Python. But I cannot find a snippet or example of how to do that.

What is the method or syntax for exposing an output property of a Python-based Pulumi program?

Answer (score 0):

The `__main__.py` file, that is the heart of your Pulumi program can use the `pulumi.export` method.

For example:

```py
import pulumi

import infra

pulumi.export('group', infra.group)
pulumi.export('server', infra.server)
pulumi.export('publicIp', infra.server.public_ip)
pulumi.export('publicHostName', infra.server.public_dns)
```